# Function createbox with parameters width and height

Tags: javascript, function, expression

Hey guys i'm wondering how to create this function

````
 ``` const rectangle = function createsquare(height,width){




}```
````

i'm supposed to be able to console.log(rectangle.width). / (rectangle.height)

find it difficult to understand function expressions when i just got used a little bit to functions.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Post some JavaScript that shows you tried to do something, not an empty function. We don't write the code for you, we fix the broken code you have. See [ask] and how to post a [mcve].

Comment: You are supposed to make a new function that accepts values for the height and the width and then uses those to make a rectangle. This is a building block in your learning to write functions, so you should refer to your notes or the instructional material and write that function yourself.

Comment: You can post your function code here after you've tried it.

Answer (score 0):

1- you must select a parent for your created element

2- create your element.

3- create your function that will append your element to the parent

4- call the function on load or click.

5- style your created element in the function or outside of it. both are ok.

6- console log the values you want.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
var rectagle = document.createElement("div");

function create() {
    parent.append(rectagle);

    
rectagle.style.width = "200px"
rectagle.style.height = "100px"
rectagle.style.border = "1px solid red"

}

create();

console.log(rectagle.style.width)
console.log(rectagle.style.height)
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```

According to your comments, How about this, I hope it's what you want.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
var rectagle = document.createElement("div");

function create(width, height) {

    width = "200px";
    height = "100px";

    parent.append(rectagle);

rectagle.style.width = width;
rectagle.style.height = height;
rectagle.style.border = "1px solid red";

console.log(width, height);

}

create();
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, maybe i was unclear sorry. I should create the function "createRectangle" that takes the two parameters and returns an object  with the attributes "width and height". Example code of how to output ``` const rectangle = createRectangle {} then when i console.log(rectangle.height) i should get the value 15 , and when i console.log(rectangle.width) output 20

Comment: how do i get these values into the parameters to begin with?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. why do you want to return width and height? if you tell me maybe I can understand. BTW, I actually answered your question according to the info in your question.

Comment: Yeaah thanks Willpower7 my first post...and i was unclear. I'm trying to create a function "expression i think atleast what i need to solve this problem.  The function should take two parameters and return the attributes width and height , it's not based on html , javascript only. this is the code example i got ```const square = function createSquare (15,20)``` , the parameters and when i write the function/call it with console.log console.log(square.height) should output 15 and console.log(square.width) should output 20

Comment: how do i get the values 15 and 20 into the ```const square = function createSquare(width,height)``` parameters

Comment: Hope that explains it better that's all the info i got....

Comment: check my update. if it's not what you want, then I will follow your question and see who can answer it to learn more.